# VBA to Create Custom Excel Workbook Based on Input

Tags: vba, excel

I have a particularly unique question that likely requires an advanced level of VBA. I have some basic experience in VBA (just takes some time looking for correct syntax). My goal is to have a macro-enabled workbook where I list certain questions on a cover page with buttons for answers. After all questions have been answered (almost like a webform), there will be a submit button that will then generate a custom excel workbook.

To further explain, I have an existing financial model framework that has modular business units A, B, and C. In some cases, I'm looking to picture the consolidated business as only modules A and B. In that event, I'd like a workbook that pulls in the worksheets for modules A and B into the workbook and the associated assumptions page.

Questions I have: 
1. Is this possible to anyone's knowledge?
2. Where would you suggest starting as far as the VBA is concerned? As mentioned, the goal would be to have these modules saved down in the same folder as this excel-based "webform" and allowing me to create a custom workbook that imports certain modules based on the questionnaire.

Comment: Can you post an example of your work so far ? ie: a picture of the page itself with the button options etc. Anything is possible.

Comment: Hi - unfortunately I have not made any headway. I'm not here to look for someone to code for me, moreso looking for someone who may have approached a project like this and can point me to some syntax that may help. I am just breaking ground on this and I scrubbed the internet with no luck on discussing methods to import worksheets from another workbook based on an input response.

Comment: I would start by creating a page with the checkboxes and information you want to gather, then work on the code a piece at a time until you get the desired results (using If -Then statements). Then work on streamlining your code, and putting it in modules.